# Adding :await_data flag to mongo ruby driver cursor

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I would like to reduce polling a capped collection and therefor add :await_data flag to a cursor. I am however not sure, how to achieve this with Mongo Ruby Driver.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moped seems to implement awaitData by default, so I am going to use that until the official driver adds support.